# don't find _corrupt_record column pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I am trying to select the _corrupt_record but i can't find it.
In my case, all column should be corrupted. The column does not appear. I've tried to filter it without success.

```
   schema = StructType([
      StructField("TestID", DecimalType(25,10), True),
      StructField("Key", DecimalType(25,10), True),
      StructField("Company", DecimalType(25,10), True),
       StructField("Client", DecimalType(25,10), True),
       StructField("Project", DecimalType(25,10), True),
       StructField("ingestdatetime", DecimalType(25,10), True),
       StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True)
    ])
    
    df = spark.read.csv(
        '/mnt/jakichan/isgood/ingestdatetime=20210202231912',
        schema=location_schema,
        header=True,
        sep=",",
        mode="PERMISSIVE",
        columnNameOfCorruptRecord="_corrupt_record",
    ).cache()
    df.select("_corrupt_record")
```

[image]

---

EDIT :

I think i had to add the column manually

```
spark_reader = spark.read.option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_records").option("enforceSchema", "true") #not sure it plays any role here 
_corrupt_records_column = [StructField("_corrupt_records", StringType(), True)] 
schema_with_corrupt_records_column = StructType(schema.fields + _corrupt_records_column)
```

Then put schema_with_corrupt_records_column in the place of the applied schema and then it worked for me i think.

Comment: Hay, did you find any solution? I am having same problem. cant access that "_corrupt_record" column.

Comment: just edited, i hope it works, i did re tested it

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your solution clearly, can edit and give full process? also I tried your solution but it did not worked.